# Eclipselink fetch-join lazy associations of a subclass

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I want to fetch a lazy association, which is present on a subclass only.
In Hibernate, it is possible to use fetch treat joins, for example

```
select a from A a left join fetch treat(a.parent as Child) u left join fetch child.some
```

Where `child.some` is an association which is present on `Child` entity only.

But we use **Eclipselink** ver 2.6.3. AFAIK JPA doesn't cover this problem, fetch treat is not supported by Eclipse. I have already tried eclipse fetch hints with no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in EclipseLink by default (I believe it is a bug). But there is working workaround in Joiner library (`InheritanceJoiningCustomizer` in https://github.com/encircled/Joiner)